# if statement with variable comparison not working in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, comparison

I'm trying to write a very simple script to check whether iptables are already updated for Synergy to work. The current script is:

```
if [[ $SYNERGY = "yes" ]]
then
    echo "Synergy is active"
else
    sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 24800 -j ACCEPT
    export SYNERGY=yes
fi
```

But it does not work (I'm always asked for the sudo password each time I open a new terminal)
I also tried with this modified version, but the result is the same

```
syn="yes"
if [ "$SYNERGY" = "$syn" ]
then
    echo "Synergy is active"
else
    sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 24800 -j ACCEPT
    export SYNERGY=yes
fi
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: How is `SYNERGY` variable getting set?

Comment: it might be asking root password to execute the command `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 24800 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @anubhava variable SYNERGY is set in the export command in the else statement

Comment: @RBH scope of the script is just to avoid passing the sudo password each time I open a new terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expecting this to be run from one terminal/shell session and to affect other unrelated terminals/shell sessions then the issue is that that isn't how `export` works.

`export` sets the variable in the environment of the current process so that any processes spawned from this process also have it in their environment. Notice how I said "spawned from"? It only applies to processes that process spawns. Unrelated processes aren't affected.

If you want something globally checkable then you either need a flag/lock/state file of some sort or an actual runtime check of the iptables configuration.

Comment: My first attempt was exactly to check iptables, but I soon understood it was the wrong way to approach the problem, as to check iptables I need to be root and I fall again in the password checking each time I open a new terminal. Do you have any suggestion to find a simple solution? As you understood I didn't work too much in linux scripting

Comment: @sthor69 Why is this something you need to be doing often? Can you not just set this as the normal configuration of the system and be done with it? As I said in my answer you can use a flag/lock/state file instead of an exported variable for the check (but then you also need to ensure that the file is cleaned up when appropriate).

Comment: As I said I'm rather a newbie in linux scripting, so I'd like to find a solution working with file and I don't know how to manage flags and states. Before starting working on them, I tried another solution that seems to work, putting the iptables command in /etc/profile. Is there any drawbacks with this solution?

Comment: @sthor69 `flags` and `state` aren't magic terms. They are descriptive ones. The point was that you get to maintain a file (somewhere in the filesystem) which indicates that the iptables rule has been added and test that file instead of the variable. And yes, putting it in `/etc/profile` is not a good solution but it is on the right path to making it a proper system setting. What distribution is this?

Comment: It is an Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Then I would look at the Ubuntu documentation and see if they discuss how to make system firewall changes. There are likely a number of ways (a quick google search shows at least two).

Comment: After year of usage I still have to learn how to fully exploit Google :-) Found iptables-presistent package that solves the issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just to help those who have the same question, this is how I managed to persist firewall settings:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-presistent
```

and then the rules specified in the files rules.v4 or rules.v6 in /etc/iptables are automatic loaded at startup